# Обводка текста на чистом СSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

Хочу сделать обводку текста как на макете, но никак не выходит.
Вот как должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что получилось у меня:

```css
.box-design {
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: $boxGray;
  font-family: GBold;
  font-size: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-first">
  <p class="box-design">DES</p>
</div>
```

Comment: а где картинка?

Answer (score 10):

Для разнообразия можно рассмотреть использование SVG

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="350" height="200" viewBox="0 0 330 200" >
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#111111" />
    <text x="10" y="150" font-size="150px" font-family="sans-serif" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" > DES </text>
</svg>
```

Добавляем буквально одну строчку и можно сделать анимацию обводки

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="350" height="200" viewBox="0 0 330 200" >
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#111111" />
    <text x="10" y="150" font-size="150px" stroke-dasharray="25" font-family="sans-serif" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" > DES 
         <!-- Анимация обводки -->
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="2s" values="300;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </text>
</svg>
```

### +SVG Filter

Для обводки используются SVG фильтры: `feColorMatrix` и `feMorphology`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="350" height="200" viewBox="0 0 330 200" >
    <filter id="outText" 
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300%" height="300%">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="4" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="1" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0.2
                             0 0 0 0 0.1
                             0 0 0 0 0.5
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#111111" />
    <text x="10" y="150" filter="url(#outText)" font-size="150px" stroke-dasharray="0" font-family="sans-serif" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" > DES 
        
    </text>
</svg>
```

*Тот же вариант + анимация строки*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="350" height="200" viewBox="0 0 330 200" >
    <filter id="outText" 
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="300%" height="300%">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="5" result="e1" />
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="1" result="e2" />
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0.2
                             0 0 0 0 0.1
                             0 0 0 0 0.9
                             0 0 1 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#111111" />
    <text x="10" y="150" filter="url(#outText)" font-size="150px" stroke-dasharray="20" font-family="sans-serif" fill="none" stroke="silver" stroke-width="4"  > DES 
         <!-- Анимация обводки -->
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="5s" values="300;0" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо!

Comment: @VadimChorniy сейчас ещё добавлю с SVG filter

Comment: @VadimChorniy Хотите добавлю ещё ответ с интересными вариантами анимаций уже самих .букв. Мне кажется, что текстовый эффекты, если они конечно, "не вырви глаз", могут оживить веб страничку

Comment: Очень хочу! Заранее спасибо

Comment: @VadimChorniy это будет дополнительный ответ, так как совершенно другие эффекты, не обводка, а сами буквы.

Answer (score 8):

Используйте `text-shadow`

```css
.box-design {
  text-shadow: 
    -1px 0 0 red, /* Тень влево */
    0 -1px 0 red, /* Тень вверх */
    1px 0 0 red, /* Тень вправо */
    0 1px 0 red; /* Тень вниз */
  font-size: 150px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-first">
  <p class="box-design">DES</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш вариант помог!)

Answer (score 8):

Можно использовать `text-shadow`, как в соседнем ответе, но тогда не будет прозрачности у самих букв. Поэтому, всё таки `-webkit-text-stroke`:

```css
body { background: radial-gradient(#d808, #000f) no-repeat; }

.box-design {
  margin: 0;
  font: 150px Arial;
  text-align: center;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-first">
  <p class="box-design">DES</p>
</div>
```

Comment: по поводу className.. проект на Реакте, забыл изменить тут.